# How to display image in android?

Tags: java, android, image, android-glide

I have a problem for displaying image, the problem is glide can't process image from storage file path(uri), Could anyone help me?

This is my Code

```
TextView browsefile, filename;
ImageView gambar;
int RequestFile = 2;
Context mContext;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    browsefile = findViewById(R.id.browsefile);
    filename = findViewById(R.id.filename);
    gambar = findViewById(R.id.gambarfile);
    mContext = MainActivity.this;

    browsefile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startOptionBrowseFile();
        }
    });


}

private void startOptionBrowseFile() {
    Intent openFileIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    openFileIntent.setType("*/*");
    startActivityForResult(openFileIntent, RequestFile);

}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RequestFile && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null){
        Uri selectedFile = data.getData();


        File path = new File(selectedFile.getPath());

        path.mkdirs();
        Glide.with(mContext).load(path).into(gambar);
        
        filename.setText(selectedFile.getPath());


    }
}
```

Updated ,
i've found the solution, i try to use Bitmap and its work,

```
Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(),selectedFile);
            Glide.with(mContext).load(bitmap).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
                    .skipMemoryCache(true)
                    .into(gambar);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

and this is the error
[image]

Comment: Can the App really access this file?

Comment: Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. If you post images of code or error messages, make sure you also copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly. Please see [Why may I not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/208273)—the same reasoning applies to error messages as well. Posts in which required text content is only present in images are likely to be closed as lacking enough details.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Glide.with(mContext).load(selectedFile.getPath()).into(gambar);
```

Comment: same bro , still can't display the image,

Answer (score 0):

```
Glide.with(mContext)
.load(new File(selectedFile.getPath())) 
.into(gambar);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer bro, but it same like my code :D